# Anyway can I extract filter segment from EntityQuery?

Tags: breeze, entitymanager

I am building EntityQuery. 
Now I would like to get filter segment out of it? I know toString() will give me human readable string, but I want actual filter string that will be sent to fetch data along with URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
var queryString: string = this._manager.metadataStore.toQueryString(query);
```

manager being your EntityManager and query being the EntityQuery.

**Result**

```
SomeEntity?$filter=FirstFilter%2Fany(x1%3A%20x1%2FLicenseTypeId%20ne%2016730)&$expand=FirstFilter%2CFirstFilter%2FPartners%2CAddresses&$inlinecount=allpages
```

and here is an alternative that I don't quite like as much:

```
var anotherway = query._toUri(manager.metadataStore);
```